# How to add line break between string in UILabel through IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

I have a `UILabel`, which has a string. Between the certain text in string, I have to add some text in **bold/Italic/letter symbol** (like registered). My app supports also for iOS 4. So, I took an another label to show these(bold/Italic/letter symbol) text.

Here the problem is, when I am giving space in `UILabel` text through `IBOutlet`. It makes a next line but I want space in the line where I put an another label.

Please suggest me something to get it working as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show some screenshot. It's kinda confusing to follow your question.

Comment: For iOS4 use [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) to display attributed text. Downside AFAIK, you need to add this via code and cannot use interface builder.

Comment: @Sudhir I have edited your question. If my edit was wrong, don't hesitate to revert back the changes.

Comment: @Dinesh Raja You have worked fine. Thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you should calculate each text length and set frames for each labels accordingly

```
CGSize size =[titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(titleLabel.frame.size.width, 200) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different type of text in single label you can use `NSMutableAttributedString`

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` in iOS below 6.0 also but for that you have to create a subclass of `UILabel` and you have to do the customization in `drawRect` method.

If you want to use attributed string in iOS below 6.0 then you can in the following way in the subclass of `UILabel`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// flip the coordinate system
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// draw
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)_attributedString);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 0.0, 15.0);
CTLineDraw(line, context);

// clean up
CFRelease(line);
}
```

Comment: What you are suggesting is available only in iOS6 and above. OP has asked for iOS4.

Comment: @Amar Who said NSMutableAttributedString not available in iOS 4?? and answer given by Discover is valid one too. But I don't know, If this answer going to help for OP. If you gave him -1, then remove it. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Amar As you suggested, `TTTAttributedLabel` is also using `NSMutableAttributedString` as I expected.

Comment: @DineshRaja I think you need to look at the documentation of [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html). And `TTTAttributedLabel` can be used for iOS 4.3 and above.

Comment: @Amar Why so? I think you mistaken `attributedText` property of `UILabel` with `NSMutableAttributedString` class. FYI `NSMutableAttributedString` is available from iOS 3.2 and `attributedText` property of `UILabel` is make ease of use with `NSAttributedString` in `UILabel`. I know that `attributedText` is available from iOS 6. But that's not `#Discover` meant in his answer.

Comment: @DineshRaja Read the answer, it says `single label`, I assume it means `UILabel`. Also, the question is about `UILabel`.

Comment: Yes so what. You can subclass your `UILabel` and add a property like `boldText` and `italicText`, then draw an attributed string in `drawRect:` method. And still he can achieve it with a single label just like I did here ( https://github.com/dineshrajas/HighlightLabel ) to make a highlight text using `NSMutableAttributedString`. If he don't know subclassing, then you may be right.

Comment: @DineshRaja Can you show me any code  of attributed string with UILabel which execute in ios4.0

Comment: @DineshRaja So this need to be added in the answer by Discover. The answer does not clear the point made, hence the downvote.

Comment: @Amar Thats what I said in my first comment itself too. Check out that comment in this answer. And for #ChamanSharma check out the link I given and see that `drawRect:` method and also see the codes in `TTTAttributeLabel` given by Amar . For Bonus, look at the `OHAttributedLabel` codes

Comment: @DineshRaja I think my down vote to this answer is justified. I rest my case.

Comment: @DineshRaja why do you take example of third party library, if NSAttributedstring work with UILabel , then give  simple example  and solve problem of Sudhir

Comment: @ChamanSharma The link for `HighlightLabel` library is written by myself. Now Sudhir is not available. When he is available, I will get clear about his question, then really I will help him. Why not you try to read all my comments and `THEN` ask me another question.

Answer (score 0):

you can textview instead of label

```
   UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]init];

NSString *String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div><strong style='color:#3468A5;'>This</strong><strong style='color: #4B4B4B;'>is sample string</strong></div> "];
textView.Frame=CGRectMake(10.,10,5,220);
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10,-6,0,0);
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueBold" size:14]];
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[textView setEditable:NO];

 @try
{
    SEL setContentToHTMLString = NSSelectorFromString([@[@"set", @"Content", @"To", @"HTML",   @"String", @":"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
    [textView performSelector:setContentToHTMLString withObject:String];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    // html+css could not be applied to text view, so no kerning
}
```

Comment: If you could explain your answer, then OP would be glad.

Comment: i used html string with  text view.
(what is to explain in it)

Comment: @ChamanSharma, thanks for your suggestion. But I have a string not HTML. If I got a HTML string the web view is fine to show the data.